# JavaScript not firing when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a button make a div pop up but currently I am facing an issue. The issue is that the class "toggle" is not being toggled when you click the button.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="bottom-bar">

    <div class="bottom-bar_top-info">
        <button class="bottom-bar_toggle-button">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xE88E;</i>
        </button>
        <span>More Information</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my JS:

```
    function toggle(){

        var bottom-bar = document.querySelector('.bottom-bar');
                bottom-bar.classList.toggle('toggle');

    }        

    var button = document.querySelector('.bottom-bar_toggle-button');

    button.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

and my styling:

```
.bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 76%;
  margin: 0 12%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23); }
  .bottom-bar .toggle {
    height: 100vh;
    top: 10%; }

.toggle {
  height: 100vh;
  top: 10%; }

.bottom-bar_top-info {
  text-align: center; }
  .bottom-bar_top-info span {
    opacity: 0.54; }

.bottom-bar_toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer; }
```

Here's a live example via CodePen: http://codepen.io/ZoidCraft/pen/NRBOqb

Comment: Is that a hyphen in a variable name? Hyphens means "subtract" in javascript

Comment: `bottom-bar` in JS is  equal to `bottom - bar`. See any difference?

Answer (score 1):

`bottom-bar` is not a valid variable name. Try `bottomBar`.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAjzZd)

Comment: Thank you. This has fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your pen, the variable name produces an error. Try renaming the variable `bottom-bar` to `bottomBar`and it runs.

Answer (score -2):

Use underscore(_) rather than dash(-) if you want to have your style.

the variables could be `bottom_bar` not `bottom-bar`.

Comment: You don't actually address why this is an issue, also provide a credible source explaining why the variables *should be*?

Comment: @AndrewL. I update the sentence a little bit to avoid someone's misunderstanding like you. You also don't actually dislike my answer and address why my answer is an issue. I still don't get what were you trying to explain to me. Could you give me more explanation? thanks.

Comment: The problem is you don't explain why the code isn't working; you don't present a cause, just an (in my opinion) unconventional alternative. Explain why the code doesn't work *and then* give an alternative otherwise the answer isn't complete.

Comment: @AndrewL.I got your point. Thanks.